# Differentiate TEXT and BLOB fields in MySQL C interface

Tags: mysql, c

I'm using `mysql_fetch_field_direct` to get information about the type of a given column in a dynamically fetched result set like so:

```
MYSQL_FIELD *field = mysql_fetch_field_direct(resultSet, col);
```

then I access `field->type` to check the field's type. However, I am currently stuck because I would like to take different actions depending on whether the field's type is `BLOB` or `TEXT`. However, it seems that the `enum_field_types` enum only contains `MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB`, but not `MYSQL_TYPE_TEXT` and instead marks text as BLOBs as well. This kinda makes sense given that a `TEXT` object is essentially a `BLOB` but with a special interpretation when processing the data.

However, this leaves me wondering: How can I check whether the field's actual type is `BLOB` or `TEXT`?

Comment: Did you try querying information_schema.columns view to get the more granular data type? Btw, text data type is basically a blob with a character set assigned to it.

Comment: @Shadow I did not. Thanks for the suggestion! I was hoping to avoid explicit extra queries though, but it is a good option to keep in the workaround toolbox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `field->charsetnr`.

If this value is 63, it's a binary BLOB.

If it's any other value, it's TEXT.

Here's what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-data-structures.html) (in the section describing `charsetnr`) has to say about this:

> To distinguish between binary and nonbinary data for string data types, check whether the charsetnr value is 63. If so, the character set is binary, which indicates binary rather than nonbinary data. This enables you to distinguish BINARY from CHAR, VARBINARY from VARCHAR, and the BLOB types from the TEXT types.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thanks! Are there some docs on the different values of `charsetnr` or even better: a named constant in MySQL's C API for the number `63`?

Comment: I found no documentation, and no constant in the source code, but I only searched for a few minutes. It seems to be a hard-coded integer. Example: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/trunk/client/mysqldump.cc#L3931-L3934

Comment: I found the docs, but they also only specify the hard-coded value of `63`. Nonetheless, I'll suggest an edit to your answer including a link to the documentation